# sorl-thumbnail can't show the picture

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

UPDATE: I solved this by adding urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),)
```

I use sorl-thumbnail to create image.
It really create the image in directory,but it can't get the path (firebug said 404 not found)
please help me to check.
Thank you very much.

settings.py

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

template: menu.html

```
{% load thumbnail %}
    {% thumbnail "https://www.google.com.tw/images/srpr/logo11w.png" "100x80"  as im %}
        <img src="{{  im.url  }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
    {% endthumbnail %}
```

[image]

Comment: set ``DEBUG = True `` to see why it doesnot work

Comment: did you do ``syncb`` after installing it?

Comment: But my terminal has a message ````lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/helpers.py:5:  DeprecationWarning: django.utils.simplejson is deprecated; use json instead.
  from django.utils import simplejson```` Do I have to install something??

Comment: no, you dont have to, it is just warning, nothing bad

Comment: do you use ``south``? did you do ``migrate`` ?

Comment: no I don't use south.which one should I migrate ? ```` ./manage.py schemamigration sorl-thumbnail ```` ??